# Why can't I upload config file in the POST method using Postman?

Tags: postman, http-post, multipartform-data

*Hello, I'm trying to solve my issue for so long that I had to ask someone else.*

I'm working with some API and I want to create resource using POST method via Postman. To create that resource I have to attach kubeconfig file to the POST request. This resource need to have name, description and of course config file. So I filled required fields:

[POSTMAN fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWw6a.png)

but I receive response "Bad Request":

`Invalid Input:: Does not match pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9]$'`

It's look like i don't understand how to upload files that way because my request body looks like:

```
Request Body
    metadata: "{"name": "edge01", "description": "Edge k8s cluster"}"
    file: undefine
```

In the API documentation we can find that request body should look like this:

```
Request body                                                     multipart/form-data

metadata
    object

file
    string($binary)
```

Entire POST entry below:

```
Network
Request Headers
    Accept: */*
    Postman-Token: 8857f718-bb05-404c-865a-51ee3c0abe6f
    Host: <Hidden_IP>:30461
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------175308278007362265143565
    Content-Length: 3518
Request Body
    metadata: "{"name": "edge01", "description": "Edge k8s cluster"}"
    file: undefined
Response Headers
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Date: Fri, 30 Jul 2021 10:19:58 GMT
    Content-Length: 84
Response Body
    Invalid Input:: Does not match pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9]$'↵
```

I couldn't find anything about response presented above.

If anyone needs additional information, please comment. This string($binary) is interesting but I don't understand what it means, and couldn't find any informations in POSTMAN context.

This is a piece of API yaml:

```
  /cluster-providers/{cluster-providers-name}/clusters:
parameters:
  - $ref: '#/components/parameters/clusterProviderName'
post:
  tags:
    - Clusters
  summary: Add Cluster
  description: Add a new `cluster`
  operationId: addClusterToClusterProvider
  responses:
    '201':
      description: Created
      content:
        application/json: # operation response mime type
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Metadata'
    '400':
      description: Bad Request
    '404':
      description: Not Found
    '409':
      description: Conflict
    '422':
      description: Unprocessable Entity
    '500':
      description: Internal Server Error
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data: # Media type
        schema:            # Request payload
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AppData'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `metadata` to the body under `raw`, instead of `form-data`. This should be an object, like this:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "name": "edge01",
        "description": "Edge k8s cluster"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your advice isn't correct, because I have to use `form-data` to transfer the file. Nevertheless it's really helpful! I used this `object` as value of key `metadata` and it worked. For me it's really strange syntax, but you learn all life. Thanks for your help.